# How to display loading message while instagram is loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram-api

On buzzfeed, while instagram is loading you can see a gradual moving camera icon and the word "loading", to make you understand it's loading the embed.

I throttled my network to show here what you see:

[image]

But I don't manage to get the same effect when I embed nor when I use [oembed](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/?hl=fr#oembed)

- source: https://www.instagram.com/p/4sUtwkDvI4/ => click then on the 'three little dots" on the botto right to get embed code
- jsfiddle of the embed I get https://jsfiddle.net/o47u4bxu/embedded/result/

I spotted the code that enable them to do it on https://www.buzzfeed.com/beatrizserranomolina/instasshole where, by throttling your connection, you can see too:

```
    <span style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-style:normal; font-weight:bold; position:relative; top:15px;">Loading</span></div></div>
    <p style=" line-height:32px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; padding:0; text-align:center;">
     <a href="https://instagram.com/p/3ozykPy2b8/" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; text-decoration:none;" target="_top"> View on Instagram</a></p></div><style>@-webkit-keyframes"dkaXkpbBxI"{ 0%{opacity:0.5;} 50%{opacity:1;} 100%{opacity:0.5;} } @keyframes"dkaXkpbBxI"{ 0%{opacity:0.5;} 50%{opacity:1;} 100%{opacity:0.5;} }</style></blockquote>
```

How to achieve this ? I dont think it's native / default to instagram embed but a javascript technique.

Comment: Turn off your javascript and you'll see that instagram loader is something they built and put in the background so it shows while the instagram content is loading. Pretty clever!

Comment: I ll do thanks but do you think they inject it in a third party iframe (the block of code I mention is inside the iframe tag)? I did not think it was possible to change a third party iframe (from a different domain ) for security reasons . I'll investigate, thanks for your help

Comment: An iframe can call any url it wants.